# How to extract video from SWF?

Tags: html, flash

I am on a site that I need the video file. Problem is, it is powered by flash.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJnqT.png)

The many ways to do this will not work because of this. The player is one file, and it uses something else to do this I believe. Please tell me how to get the video.

And I would love to know why this was disliked for NO apparent reason. Didn't even leave a comment.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/31705/downloading-video-from-swf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, I found a solution.

There is a chrome extension called Flash Video Downloader, which will download already viewed media or download media that is being watched.

This will work on many sites. I tested this on HBO if you are wondering.